# Ext4 secondary drive not accepted by steam

Tags: steam

My computer restarted with steam open and upon relaunching it none of my games on a secondary internal SSD were recognized. The drive is Ext4 and the relevant line from fstab is

UUID=99d2c67d-cbd0-43b4-af73-fad5a79fcd08  /media/datastorage  ext4  defaults  0  2

All of the steam games are still on the hard drive, but steam says "New steam library folder must be on a filesystem mounted with execute permissions" whenever I attempt to use the app to re-add the library.

I have tried several other fstab options recommended on this platform already. My user has full read-write permissions for this folder and drive. All of my steam library folders already have "steamapps" in all lowercase. I noticed some other users have had issues with Windows dual boot, but I do not have this and only have one Windows virtual machine set up (but not running nor on the secondary SSD).

My system information is: Ubuntu 20.04 on a Dell Precision 5550 with an i7-10850H and an NVIDIA Quadro T1000

Let me know if there's anything else I should include! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

> "New steam library folder must be on a filesystem mounted with execute permissions"

Do what the error tells you: edit `/etc/fstab` to include "exec":

```
UUID={uuid} /{mount}    auto    rw,user,auto,exec    0    0
```

as that makes it possible to execute executable.

If that is not it PM me and I'll revise it :)

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work for me. I've tried a lot of different fstab settings and none of them have fixed the issue yet. Any other ideas? Just let me know if there's any other information I need to give you! Thanks